# ember.select not working with disabled when bound variable changes

Tags: ember.js

given this code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="stateCode">StateID</label>

 {{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="controllers.state.content"
    optionValuePath="content.state"
    optionLabelPath="content.stateName"
    valueBinding="stateCode"
    class="form-control"
   disabled=isNotEditing
 }}
```

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="country">Country</label>
{{input type="text" value=country class="form-control" placeholder="Country" disabled=isNotEditing}}
</div>
```

the fields all show as disabled. However, when I toggle the **isNotEditing** property then only the {{input fields are enabled. The {{view Ember.Select field is still disabled.

Is there something else that I need to do to toggle a {{view Ember.Select disabled state ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `disabled`, you should used `disabledBinding`.  When you set `disabled` directly it's the same as statically assigning a single value that does not change (the value of `isNotEditing` and view instantiation).  I'm not sure why using `disabled` works for inputs but not for selects.  It might be a bug with the inputs...

Here's a jsbin : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/968/edit

Comment: thanks so much! this was driving me mad. I can confirm that changing **disabled=isNotEditing** to **disabledBinding="isNotEditing"** works for both my text and selects. Thanks again.

Comment: one little question, if you don't mind : is there an ember equivalent of the <datalist> [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865943/html-form-select-option-vs-datalist-option)

Comment: Hey, jmls, it's possible to use `datalist` in an Ember app, but it takes a little doing.  If you'll open another question about this I can give you an explanation and an example.  (Only so many words allowed in comments...)

Comment: question posted at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724155/can-a-datalist-be-used-with-ember-js-select)