# Can a datalist be used with ember.js select

Tags: ember.js

ember.js 1.0

I am using an ember.js select list, and was wondering if it is possible to use  instead of the normal

```
<input type=text list=browsers>
 <datalist id=browsers>
   <option value="Firefox">
   <option value="IE">
   <option value="Chrome">
   <option value="Opera">
   <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datalist` is standard HTML, so you can use it inside of Ember (for browsers that support datalist).  The only real trick is that the native Ember `input` view component doesn't pass through the `list` attribute to allow you to hook up the `datalist`.  Luckily it's very easy to extend `Ember.TextView` to make it do what you want.

```
App.DatalistText = Ember.TextField.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['list'],
  list : null
});
```

Then in your template you just do something like this:

```
{{view App.DatalistText type="text" 
    value="" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Country" 
    disabledBinding="isNotEditing"
    list="countries"
    size="50"
}}
<datalist id="countries">
  {{#each model}}
    <option {{bindAttr value="this"}}>
  {{/each}}
</datalist>
```

Here's a jsbin : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/977/edit

Comment: thanks very much - whilst that worked for me (hence the accepted answer!) I would prefer to have a select-style look and feel but be able to type other options in. However, this has been really useful in understanding how you can extend things.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose you could develop a custom widget that acts like a hybrid of an input/datalist combo and a select list, but I'm not aware of any 'native' html solution for that.  What I've done before is to have a select list and then have a small "+" button beside it.  When you click the button a modal pops up asking you to enter the new value.  When you click "save" in the modal, a new Ember model is created and added to the collection backing the select list.

Comment: @JeremyGreen But this does not work in the latest version, can you help? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zakiqigafi

Comment: @VysakhSreenivasan, as mentioned below this seems to be a known bug in the latest Ember.

Answer (score 0):

With ember.js 1.8 the following code just works:

```
{{input type="text" value="" class="form-control" list="browsers-list"}}
<datalist id="browsers-list">
{{#each b in browsers}}
  <option {{bind-attr value=b}}>
{{/each}}
</datalist>
```

Comment: But this does not work ember 1.11.3 version http://jsbin.com/kukayuzisi/1/edit?html,js

Comment: @VysakhSreenivasan looks like a known regression: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10908