# Datalist arrow not coming in ie and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Hi I am using a datalist tag for a dropdown as in the fiddle. I am getting the arrow for dropdown in chrome only. and the arrow is not coming in ie and firefox.
In firefox the search is lazy search ie; it is not based on the first letter

The fiddle is:: https://jsfiddle.net/v7fg0zc8/
pleas specify the styling if any to achieve this

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
      <input list="browsers" name="browser">
      <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Internet Explorer"></option>
          <option value="Firefox"></option>
          <option value="Chrome"></option>
          <option value="Opera"></option>
          <option value="Safari"></option>
      </datalist>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: This is just a factor of how the different browsers have implemented the feature. The Chrome devs have decided to put a drop arrow into it; the FF and IE devs decided not to. Other HTML5 input types work differently between the various browsers too. Don't get hung up about things having to look exactly the same in every browser.

Comment: @deviantfan, did you check the answer?

Comment: Try with this `Tocken input.js`

Answer (score 21):

Check with this. I've tried so many ways but not worked well. May be this is the only solution

```css
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;/* remove default arrow */
}
.myarrow:after {
    content: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9WFO.png);
    margin-left: -20px; 
    padding: .1em;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<span class="myarrow"><input list="browsers" name="browser" id="#show-suggestions"></span>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer"></option>
  <option value="Firefox"></option>
  <option value="Chrome"></option>
  <option value="Opera"></option>
  <option value="Safari"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Finally, someone who actually tries to answer ... while not perfect (eg. clicking two times in firefox required), it's the best answer so far... I guess, you'll get the bounty tomorrow

Comment: how ? Mr: Charan babu last seen this august 7 , then how can he accept this answer ?

Comment: sorry for the doubt. i heard when someone accepting the answer the only way to get bounty

Comment: I have a button for each answer to award the bounty. I didn't click yet, but it should work,

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: Here's an icon that is permanent, without loading and easily modifiable: `content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="8" height="8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="0 0 8 0 4 6 0 0" fill="black" /></svg>');`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I tested this on my machine and got the same result :(
The drop down arrow only appeared in Chrome, although in FF I could still select from the list but without a drop down arrow.

What if you just used the SELECT tag instead?

```
<select>
    <option value="Internet Explorer" >Internet Explorer</option>
    <option value="Firefox" >Firefox</option>
    <option value="Chrome" >Chrome</option>
    <option value="Opera" >Opera</option>
    <option value="Safari" >Safari</option>
</select>
```

I did some more digging on this and found this post... [HTML Form: Select-Option vs Datalist-Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865943/html-form-select-option-vs-datalist-option)

It better explains the difference between datalist and select. That could also be why my suggestion of using SELECT instead might not be appropriate. But it could also explain the lack of the arrow. I don't see anywhere in the other discussions about the arrow being a guaranteed behaviour. The datalist may still function as an auto complete, but without the drop down arrow (although I just checked this again in IE11 and it doesn't even seem to do the autocomplete).

Perhaps this can just get put down to how well different browsers implement this feature.

Comment: I am not able to type if i use a select tag right @Lucien

Comment: yeah @charanbabu . I just realised that is a problem with my suggested answer, so I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `<datalist>` element is **not** a `<select>` replacement.
The general idea is to give you the ability to set a list of predefined values for other controls [[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element), however there is no specification for how to draw that list and whether or not to show an arrow.

The arrow that you see in chrome is something that is browser independent that only chrome has.

Just as a side note - for `datetime-local` - only in chrome you will see that placeholer:

```
mm/dd/yy --:--:--
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" />
```

If you want to show the exact arrow in all browsers you will have to use some javascript code for that (you can use jquery ui's [`autocomplete` for example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)).

Comment: (As I said elsewhere here already) I know that many things are not specified and browser-dependent. But that was not the question OP did ask and I gave a bounty for. The question here is how to force it to have an arrow in all major browsers. (And yes, I do see your answer, there's no need to ask in comments)

Answer (score -3):

Well I did some searching and i immediately found this on w3schools.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp
This page clearly states that it is meant to implement auto completion. Auto completion is a feature often found in IDE's with the purpose of providing possible values while you type. In other words Firefox and IE implement it the right way. As soon as you decide to type something in the textbox, it provides you with possible options and while you type, it filters the possible options. In this case Chrome implements it rather strange by making it a dropdown box. Auto completion is not supposed to work that way in the case where you would use a text input. You can use it for a dropdown box however when you use a select tag within your datalist as seen here https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-datalist-element

Comment: Commenting as a regular user: W3Schools has nothing to do with W3C, and is known to have wrong information in many cases. The real W3 says nothing about datalist being for autocompletion, or if it should have an arrow (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) (that's the actual problem, browsers can implement it how they want)

Comment: ...and commenting as bounty-giver: I know the things written in my previous comment. Nonetheless, the question here is how to force it to have an arrow. Citing wrong sources that it is not meant to have one is not an answer.

Comment: I edited it. Also W3 clearly states that you need to use a select tag when you want a dropdown box  As said by W3: In the more elaborate case, the datalist element can be given contents that are to be displayed for down-level clients that don't support datalist. In this case, the option elements are provided inside a select element inside the datalist element. So what i said is still correct.

Comment: `Also W3 clearly states that you need to use a select tag when you want a dropdown box` Where? it's not in your quote, which is entirely about old browsers without any datalist support, and the following code example (which is just an example, not required). Did you forget that there is already a dropdown box without select, and it's perfectly allowed by the standard? The only problem is the arrow.