# FireFox datalist does not open until double click

Tags: html, firefox, html-datalist

```
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

In Chrome/Edge/Safari, clicking on this input once, opens the datalist.  However in FireFox, it requires a second click on the input element to open the datalist.  Is there a way to get this behavior consistent with other browsers?

The expected result is for a single click to open the data list, just as works in other browsers.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041925/datalist-arrow-not-coming-in-ie-and-firefox

Answer (score 3):

just add this to **onmouseover="focus();"** to your input like this

```
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" onmouseover="focus();"/>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```