# How to populate a select box with JSON from Grails Controller

Tags: javascript, json, grails

I have to populate a select box with all avaliable Disciplines that are stored in my DB.

So, in DisciplineController I created an action like this:

```
def getDisciplinesJson() {

def discList = Discipline.getAll()
return discList as JSON

}
```

Is that the right way to get disciplines as JSON, and how do I call this action and, using Javascript for example, populate a select box, something like this:

```
<select id=disc-select> </select>
```

This select box appears in other page, Student create, for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways. For example using JQuery

```
<script>
  function loadDisciplines() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "${createLink(controller: 'DisciplineController', action: 'getDisciplinesJson')}",
      success: function (data) {
        //...
// Parse JSON, create select box etc..
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

And change "return discList as JSON" to "render discList as JSON"

Also you can create template with code:

```
<select id=disc-select> 
<g:each in="${discList}" var="disc">
<option value="${disc?.id}">${disc?.name}</option>
</g:each>
</select>
```

And return from controller already rendered template:

```
render template:"pathToTemplate/thisTEmplate", model:[discList:discList]
```

Then in the loadDisciplines() success block you need to put only:

```
$('#disciplines-div').html(data);
```

where #disciplines-div is

```
<div id="disciplines-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind altering select to data lists then even easier is dataList HTML5 supports data lists and you can find an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865943): and show here:

```
<input type=text list=browsers>
<datalist id=browsers>
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="IE">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

If you wanted to see auto complete working with dataLists then check out [boselecta](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-boselecta-plugin). I have used it for auto completion and you can find that [example here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-boselecta-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/views/boselecta/_genAutoComplete.gsp#L8). There are some further complexity of parsing the json as data lists but it is all within that page..

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is 'How to populate a select box with JSON from Grails Controller' but looking at your example. Why do you need to populate it with JSON?

In this case a `<g:select>` tag could be a simpler approach.

`<g:select id="disc-select" from="${my.package.Discipline.list()}" name="myparam"/>`

This is assuming that you´re using GSPs