# HTML5 datalist only option value hidden

Tags: javascript, html, opencart, datalist

I want to hide `datalist` value. Am using this code

```
<input list="options" oninput="console.log(this.value);" />
<datalist id="options">
  <option value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2</option>
  <option value="3">Product 3</option>
</datalist>
```

I mean in the inputbox this showing `values` and `product 1` 
i need to show only `product 1,2,&3...`

hide value (1,2,3)
[image].

**Note:** Here am passing value `1,2,3` so i just want to hide that only

here my code https://jsfiddle.net/69u5Leoa/

Comment: @DeepakYadav: Am asking different

Comment: check the marked `Duplicate` the output requires same thing.

Comment: you asking product autocomplete

Comment: Ya your are correct..!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use select, because for the select element, the user is required to select one of the options you've given.

For the datalist element, it is suggested that the user select one of the options you've given, but he can actually enter anything he wants in the input.

you can see this to get more information [HTML Form: Select-Option vs Datalist-Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865943/html-form-select-option-vs-datalist-option)

```
<select id="options">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="3">Product 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks you @Rex actually am passing the product values for `insert` eg: if i select `value="1"` insert `product 1` details

Comment: this is my code `<option value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></option>`

Comment: i just want to hide `<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>`

Comment: Ha ha bro nice one. But i want in `autocomplete` thats why am using `datalist`

Answer (score -3):

Value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>" it can solution this problem

Comment: Thanks for replay @ComEngTr  can you write the code

Comment: Because am confusing where i want to edit

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  your answer is very short and confusing.