# get the id of selected item from html5 input list

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, input

How can I get the ID of the selected item from the input list. I can fetch the item but can not fetch the ID of the selected item.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label>
        <span>&nbsp;Selected Items</span>
        <input list="username" runat="server" id="usernameInput" class="form-control input_list" placeholder="FACULTY" required="required" />
            <datalist id="username" runat="server"></datalist>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <label>
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Selected HTML5 Input</span>
        <input type="text" id="input_selected" runat="server" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</div>
```

I want to display USER_NAME in the input list to the user but want to fetch USER_ID of the selected USER_NAME in the codebehind page.

```
public void GetUserName()
        {
                string strQuery = "SELECT USER_ID, USER_NAME FROM TBL_USER";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
                DBConnection conn_ = new DBConnection();
                DataTable dt = conn_.SelectData(cmd);

                var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(String.Format("<option value='{0}'>", dt.Rows[i][1]));
                }
                username.InnerHtml = builder.ToString();
                usernameInput.Attributes["list"] = username.ClientID;
        }
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                input_selected.Value = usernameInput.Value;
        }
```

This gives me the USER_NAME but I want to fetch USER_ID in the code behind page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Some concerns regarding HTML5 `datalist` element from [HTML Form: Select-Option vs Datalist-Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865943/html-form-select-option-vs-datalist-option):

> If we focus on the use of `<datalist>` as a list of options for a text
>   field then here are some specific differences between that and a
>   select box:
>
> - **A `<datalist>` fed text box has a single string for both display label and submit.** A select box can have a different submit value vs.
>     display label `<option value='ie'>Internet Explorer</option>`.

As mentioned above, the display label text & value for `datalist` has same string, so that you can't use `builder.Append(String.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", ...)` placeholder in a `datalist` as generally used in `select` element.

a) If you still want to use `datalist` & fetch user ID instead of user name, you can store `DataTable` contents inside `Session` (or other instance which able to hold `DataTable` during runtime, hence no need to re-query the DB again) and perform [`DataTable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) query during `btnSubmit_Click` event afterwards:

```
public void GetUserName()
{
    // other stuff

    DataTable dt = conn_.SelectData(cmd);
    Session["Datatable"] = dt;

    // other stuff
}

// Button click event handler
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = usernameInput.Value;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Datatable"];
    string expression = "USER_NAME = '" + value + "'";

    DataRow[] result = dt.Select(expression);

    input_selected.Value = result[0][0].ToString(); // ensure the result is only a single user ID result
}
```

b) If you willing to change `datalist` to plain `select` element which able to contain different data label & form submit value, use aforementioned `option` placeholder before:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     // if the DataTable has 2 columns,
     // 0 = USER_ID, 1 = USER_NAME
     builder.Append(String.Format("<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>", dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()));
}

// Button event handler
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    input_selected.Value = username.Value;
}

<%-- datalist changed to select element --%>
<select id="username" runat="server" ...></select>
```

Then, you can remove `input` tag named `usernameInput` required by `datalist` & use client-side autocomplete feature with JS.