# Activate button when input value is validated with datalist

Tags: javascript, validation, datalist

I’ve listed below action code. Could you guys help me out with it?

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" list="colours" name="colours">
   <datalist id="colours">
      <option value="Red" data-id="1">
      <option value="Blue" data-id="2">
      <option value="Green" data-id="3">
      <option value="Black" data-id="4">
      <option value="White" data-id="5">
   </datalist>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="confirm">Zapisz</button>
</form>
```

1. How to make the „Save button” be inactive until the input value exactly matches the datalist options?
2. How to transfer the contain of the code from data-id?

Cheers, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first set your button to be disabled by adding the disabled attribute. Note, I added an id attribute to your button and the form. There's also a `<p>` tag to use as a result/error message but you can customize this.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" list="colours" name="colours">
   <datalist id="colours">
      <option value="Red" data-id="1">
      <option value="Blue" data-id="2">
      <option value="Green" data-id="3">
      <option value="Black" data-id="4">
      <option value="White" data-id="5">
   </datalist>
  <button id="myButton" disabled type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="confirm">Zapisz</button>
</form>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Then add a listener in javascript to listen to any changes to the input form, and run a validation check by looping the input value over the options. If the validation passes, it sets the disabled attribute to false. If not, it will throw a message in the bottom.

Here is the javascript code

```
  window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('change', myFunction);


  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
    let options = document.getElementById("colours").options;
    let selectionMade = false;
    let selectedValue = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if(document.getElementById("input").value == options[i].value) {
        selectedValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
        selectionMade = true;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Selected : " + selectedValue + ".";
        document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = false; 
      } 
    }

    if (selectionMade === false) {
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Please only select one of the available choices";
    }
   }
}
```

Here is a link to a working [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/jiyofipeca/edit?html,js,output).

Updated: to answer question 2 of getting the data-id attribute of the option selected.

To get the data-id attribute of the option selected, in your javascript you can get using this way:

```
let selectedDataId = options[i].getAttribute('data-id');
```

After you get this value, you can update a hidden input form inside your form so that the value is submitted along.

Here is a link to an updated [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/woxusuyuja/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I do want to add that if you want your users to only select one of your data-list options, you can consider implementing select tag instead which is a better choice.
See this answer for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002118/6828976).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need. 
Can you answer also to second question? When user is sending form, server got `[colours] = Blue`. Is there any possibility to get `[colours] = 2`?

Comment: Yes, I know that there is `select` tag, but when You use it, You dont have live hint, which is very usefull when there is hundreds options.

Comment: Updated my post to answer your second question too.